# maintaining Package vs Sub module

Tags: python, package, git-submodules, python-packaging

I am working on a big project which includes a number of different repositories.
After some discussions we decided that we might need to create packages from a number of repos.

The problem is that we have two different repositories using the same submodule.
Repository named **Control-1** and repository named **Control-2** uses a submodule named **HW-control**.

HW-control is a core repository used by theses two other repos and the dependency goes two directions.

When testing or developing new features of Control-1 or Control-2 we are using HW-control functionalities,
but at the same time when we are developing or testing features of HW-control we need to use control-1 or control-2 in order to run the tests.

The dilemma is if we make the HW-control a package, on every new feature we develop, we need to release a new package version, update it on our environments and then run the tests with Control-1 or Control-2.
Or, edit the package files directly and from there I can see the mess it will create.

And on the other hand, it will be much easier to maintain releases and use it as a packge rather than a submodule.

So the question is, should we make HW-control a package? or should we keep it as a submodule?
what is the correct way or the better option of doing it right?

Thank you all in advanced! Will appreciate any help!